# How to resolve memory warning issue in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I'm showing the images in collection view after click from camera. I got the warning after click 60 images from camera with below error like:

1). negative or zero item sizes are not supported in the flow layout
2). Received memory warning.

I used the instrument: it is showing message like this:

1). Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue

Please help me solve this problem.

Comment: Can u explain Exact Error and Scenario with some code?

Comment: are you storing them in an array or dictionary?

Comment: you should show some code that you tried so that other can understand.. KINDLY SHOW SOME CODE in your question.

Comment: yes i'm storing in array this <UIImage: 0x1004f28f0>, {1080, 1328} and showing in collectionview ,                                    imgView_BackGround.image =[delegate.ary_TotalImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
                [imgView_BackGround setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];

Comment: You need to write the original images to disk and only display a resized (smaller) version of your images. This will keep the memory usage down.

Comment: after click picture i'm showing image by using below code.                                                                         -(void)reloadCollectionView
{
    [collView_Product performBatchUpdates:^{
    [collView_Product reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0]];
    } completion:nil];
}

Comment: #pragma mark- Auto scroll image collectionview

-(void)AutoScroll
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:10 delay:2 options:(UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse + UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat) animations:^{  [collView_Product scrollToItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:delegate.ary_TotalImages.count-1 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionRight animated:YES];
    } completion:nil];
}